# Filtering a video stream using GPUImage2

Tags: ios, gpuimage, metalkit, video-toolbox

I have access to the `CVPixelBufferRef` for each frame and want to apply the `ChromaKey` filter to it before rendering it.

So far, the only solution I can think of is to first convert the pixel buffer to an image. Here is my barebones solution just for PoC.

```
var cgImage: CGImage?
VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, nil, &cgImage)
let image = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage!).filterWithOperation(filter!)
```

Once I get the filtered image, I pass it to an `MTKView` to draw.

So my specific question is, can I avoid converting the pixel buffer to an image and still use `GPUImage2` for the filter?